# Specifying time range for time-series observations Weather Insights API

Tags: ibm-cloud, weather

In https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Weather/index.html it says,

*The time-series observations include past observations that occurred during a specified number of hours, up to and including the last 24 hours for the location requested. You can supply the number of hours to request observations for. For example, if you supply parameter hours=5, you get the current observation and all other observations recorded within the last 5 hours. If you supply parameter hours=23, you get the current observations and all the observations that were recorded within the last 24 hours.*

But supplying an 'hours' parameter stops the API from working, and the parameter doesn't show up in API docs: 
https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/rest-api/#!/twc_observations_timeseries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in the docs. We'll get them updated as soon as possible. The [API docs](https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/rest-api/#!/twc_observations_timeseries) are correct.